# Register a variable output with Ansible CLI / Ad-Hoc

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

Can I register the output of a task? Is there an argument with `ansible` command for that ?

This is my command:

> ```
> ansible all -m ios_command -a"commands='show run'" -i Resources/Inventory/hosts
> ```

I need this, because the output is a dictionary and I only need the value for one key. If this is not possible, is there a way to save the value of that key to a file?

Comment: Registering task results to process in subsequent tasks is a thing in ansible playbooks, yet you are using an `ansible` ad-hoc command, which will return you back to linux shell.

Comment: @ilias-sp is there a way to save in a file the value of one key of the dictionary? Similar to `local_action` in the playbooks. (What I want is different from redirecting the `stdout` of the command!)

Comment: if you still want to use the above ad-hoc command you will need: 1. some plugins to format the output to json (at ansible.cfg, i read in some other question here its possible) and 2. some tool (`jq` linux utility?) to extract from the json the value you need. all in all i think its easier to work with playbooks, but maybe i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

I have found that you can convert ansible output to json when executing playbooks with "`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json`" preceding the "`ansible-playbook`" command. Example:

> ```
> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook Resources/.Scripts/.Users.yml
> ```

This will give you a large output because it also shows each host's facts, but will have a key for each host on each task.

This method is not possible with `ansible` command, but it's output is similar to json. It just shows "`10.20.30.111 | SUCCESS =>`" before the main bracket.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/9iWn0uBOc5A/c3iPlbYsBwAJ)

Answer (score 2):

Set the following in your ansible.cfg under the [defaults] group

> bin_ansible_callbacks=True

Then as @D_Esc mentioned, you can use
`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible all -m ios_command -a"commands='show run'" -i Resources/Inventory/hosts` 
and can get the json output which you can try to parse.

I have not found a way to register the output to a variable using ad-hoc commands