# How do I register a variable in ansible-console?

Tags: ansible

Well, the title says pretty much all.

When running a playbook, you can always:

```
- name: my task
  register: variable_name
  some_module:
    some_args: true
```

However, when running `ansible-console`, how do I register the result of a module execution in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vars file and add your variable to it

```
---
somevar: somevalue
```

- Start you ansible console
- Set the host or group you want to work on `cd hostgroup`
- At the console prompt: `include_vars myvarsfile.yml`
- You'll see it set the var for every host in the group/host your have specified.

According to the documentation Ansible  v4 seems to take `--extra-vars` on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

`register` is only accessible in playbooks launched with `ansible-playbook`. `ansible-console` is just a wrapper over the base `ansible` to launch ad_hoc commands. You would have to parse the returned json yourself and call `set_fact` with the result. I didn't see any command available in the console to do that.

Meanwhile, you can have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465035/register-a-variable-output-with-ansible-cli-ad-hoc) where there is an interesting possible workaround using callback plugin that might be usable with console.